# Require Postcode on Signup

Tags: magento2, register, registration

Is it possible to make the postcode required on signup? I've taken a look under the customer configuration in admin panel and cannot find an option to make the postcode required.

I have created a module that adds a Customer EAV to request the postcode, but I want to do this without having to create a module; from the Magento Admin panel.

Is this possible without having to create a module?

Comment: May you please share the filename with its path and some code so that we can drill deep into this issue ?

Comment: @VibhoreJain I understand the rules of StackExchange, I'm a mod on SO. This question has no code assosiated because I'm asking is it possible to do this from within the admin panel? I can already create a module and add a poscode field, but that means there's 2 postcode fields the user has to enter (one on signup, one of order). Ideally I want to use the postcode field from magento on the signup form. If it's not possible from Magento's CMS the answer should be "no". Hence why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has a built in feature that allows the user to specify countries for optional post code.

In that feature, you can remove validation for selected countries.

Settings can be found in: Admin Panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > General > Country options > Zip/Postal Code is Optional for

You have to un-tick the "Use system value" and un-select the countries that you want the post code to be validated for.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.